# How to find XML element by the pattern of attribute’s value

Tags: c#, xml

I need to search XML element by the pattern of the value of an attribute.

The current XML file I’m working on looks like:

```
<root>
   <items>
      <item Id=“001” name=“Foo001”></item>
      <item Id=“002” name=“Foo002”></item>
      <item Id=“003” name=“Boo001”></item>
   </items>
</root>
```

I need to search for the element that the value of its name attribute starts with “Boo”

I’ve tried to use the following code (found on google) to search but it is not working

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(myXmlFilePath);
XmlNode match = doc.SelectSingleNode(“/root/items/item[substring(@name,1,3)=‘Boo’]”);
Console.WriteLine(match.Value.ToString());
```

Could anyone show me how to implement what I needed in C# please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong quotes in both, your XML and the XPATH.

- Change “ to "" in your XML
- Change ‘ to ' in your XPATH

  ```
  <root>
   <items>
       <item Id="001" name="Foo001"></item>
       <item Id="002" name="Foo002"></item>
       <item Id="003" name="Boo001"></item>
   </items>
  </root>

  XmlNode match = doc.SelectSingleNode("/root/items/item[substring(@name,1,3)='Boo']");
  ```

In order to read the results:

```
// read the attribute name
Console.WriteLine(match.Attributes["name"].Value);

// read the text in item        
Console.WriteLine(match.InnerText);
```

Comment: I posted this question by using my iPad(the company banned stackoverflow on company PC), so that the quotes seems wrong. My code on VS2013 have no compilation error, but a nullReferenceException occurred when executing it.

Comment: I updated my answer. The match.Value is always null. Look at the updated code.

Comment: BTW: No need for `.ToString()` on `.InnerText`.

Comment: @UweKeim - you are correct. Updated the answer. tnx